# What is the derivative of $\mathbf{a}^TX^2\mathbf{a}$ with respect to the symmetric matrix $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

Given a constant vector $\mathbf{a}\in{\rm I\!R}^n$ and a real symmetric matrix $X\in{\rm I\!R}^{n\times n}$, what is the derivative of $\mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a}$ with respect to $X$?

---

I tried a simple example using $n=2$, with the following vector and matrix :
$$
\mathbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} \qquad X = \begin{bmatrix} x & z \\ z & y \end{bmatrix}
$$

What we want to differentiate is
$$ 
\mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a} = a^2 (a^2 + z^2) + 2 ab (xz+yz) + b^2 (z^2 + y^2) 
$$

Which gives the following result
$$ 
\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a}}{\partial X} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a}}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a}}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a}}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
2
\begin{bmatrix}
a^2 x + abz &  a^2z + abx + aby + b^2z \\
a^2z + abx + aby + b^2z & b^2 y + abz
\end{bmatrix} 
$$ 
I tried to re-write this to end up with something meaningful, but I could only write

$$ 
\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}^T X^2 \mathbf{a}}{\partial X} = 2X\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^T + 2 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a^2 z + ab y \\
abx + b^2z & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and I do not know what to do with the matrix on the right...

---

What I would like is a valid expression for any $n > 1$ involving only $X$ and $\mathbf{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Fréchet derivative of $f(X) =\mathbf{a}^TX^2\mathbf{a}$ is given by

$$\partial_{X_0}f(h) = \mathbf{a}^TX_0 h\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{a}^Th X_0 \mathbf{a}$$

Comment: Related: http://thousandfold.net/cz/2013/11/12/a-useful-trick-for-computing-gradients-w-r-t-matrix-arguments-with-some-examples/

Answer (score 0):

$\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$Let $U$ be an unconstrained matrix
and use a colon denote the trace function in product form, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = B:A$$
Write the function using the colon product and calculate the unconstrained derivative.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= aa^T:U^2 \\
d\phi &= aa^T:(U\,dU+dU\,U) \\
 &= (Uaa^T+aa^TU):dU \\
\p{\phi}{U} &= Uaa^T+aa^TU \;\doteq\; G \qquad({\rm gradient}) \\
}$$
Here is recipe for converting an unconstrained gradient $G$ into the desired form
$$\eqalign{
G_S &\doteq G+G^T - {\rm Diag}(G) \\
 &= (Xaa^T+aa^TX) + (Xaa^T+aa^TX)^T -{\rm Diag}(Xaa^T+aa^TX) \\
 &= 2(Xaa^T+aa^TX) - {\rm Diag}(Xaa^T+aa^TX) \\
\\
}$$
Apply this general result to your $2\times 2$ example.
$$\eqalign{
A = Xaa^T &= \m{a^2x+abz & abx+b^2z \\ a^2z+aby & abz+b^2y} \\
B = A+A^T &= \m{2(a^2x+abz) & (abx+b^2z+a^2z+aby) \\ (a^2z+aby+abx+b^2z) & 2(abz+b^2y)} \\
G_S = 2B-{\rm Diag}(B)
  &= \m{2(a^2x+abz)&2(abx+b^2z+a^2z+aby)\\2(a^2z+aby+abx+b^2z)&2(abz+b^2y)} \\
}$$
which is the same result that you obtained.

Having provided you with the formula that you were searching for, I must warn you that it is nonsense.

What you *should* do is extract a vector of fully independent parameters from the $X$ matrix using the half-vec operation
$$\eqalign{
p &= {\rm vech}(X) = \m{x\\z\\y} \\
}$$
and solve whatever problem you have in mind in terms of this vector.

*Everyone* agrees that the following vector gradient is valid and unambiguous
$$\eqalign{
g\doteq \p{\phi}{p} &= 
\m{2(a^2x+abz) \\ 2(abx+b^2z+a^2z+aby) \\ 2(abz+b^2y)} \\
}$$
However, casting this vector into matrix form using the reverse of
the ${\rm vech}()$ function creates a ***thing*** which is difficult to interpret as a gradient, and hard to use (properly) in algorithms such as gradient descent.

Instead, you should leave the gradient in vector form and use it to
optimize/solve for the $p$ vector. Then, as a post-processing step, you can cast the solution back into matrix form $$X = {\rm unvech}(p)$$